# bash:./word:no such file or directory in cygwin64

Tags: c#, bash, cmd, cygwin

i'm using cygwin64 to run .sh file from c#.net in windows10 os.But i'm getting below error.

--> **bash:./word.sh:no such file or directory**.please check my code below.

```
 ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe");
    psi.Arguments = "--login -i C:\\cygwin64\\wordsearch.sh C:\\cygwin64\\matrix1.png";


    Process p = Process.Start(psi);
```

But below commend is working manually.

**bash word.sh matrixcheck.png**

please help me to resolve.

For step by step Details........

step1.

please check below image for my sh file details.

[image]

please check my textcleaner file image below

[image]

when i execute my c# code i'm getting output please check below image.my c# code is above in my post please check.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does `bash` understand backslashes in filename paths? More likely you will need to use forward slashes and `/mnt/c/...` . Also, did you check that the command you're actually using works? You've only shown that some other command works.

Comment: Thanks for your response ,i have checked comment is working fine while entering manually but it will not work when i call from c#.

Comment: In your question you said that `bash word.sh matrixcheck.png` is working manually. Please try if `bash --login -i E:\\code\\word.sh E:\\code\\matrixcheck.png` is working manually.

Comment: No.its not working even manually.have i missed any working directory.

Comment: The current directory when your script is run is not what you think it is. Put an explicit `cd` in a line before that. For example `cd $(dirname $0; pwd)` will change the directory to the directory of the script.

Comment: Oh ooops .Thank you.i will check...

Answer (score 1):

The error message is  `bash:./word.sh:no such file or directory`
So you are passing to bash a different string of what you are showing us.

If I try I bash

```
$ bash -l -i C:\\cygwin64\\wordsearch.sh C:\\cygwin64\\matrix1.png
bash: C:\cygwin64\wordsearch.sh: No such file or directory
```

The error does not report `./wordsearch.sh`, it reports the full path.

As the files are in the cygwin root `/` their location is

```
/wordsearch.sh /matrix1.png
```

without any `./` that instead means in the current directory where bash start.

Comment: what is the error message and what is the output of bash pwd when you are in the directory where word.sh and matrixcheck.png are located ?

Comment: and add the output of ls